# AEM Configuration

Tags: aem

Configurations are applied to an AEM instance based on run modes. How AEM determines the config file to be picked in case of multiple runmodes and multiple configurations? 
Assuming the below configs are available in an AEM project,

```
/apps
  /myproject
    - config
    - config.prod
    - config.author
    - config.active
    - config.prod.active
    - config.prod.author.active
```

which configuration gets picked or applied to an  AEM instance created with run modes *author,nosamplecontent,prod,active*?

Is there any defined set of rules(or best practices) related to config creation documented that i can refer while setting up the project

Thanks,
Jai

Comment: I think, when you create a aem instance using java -jar command, you can mention the run mode of aem instance prod, stage, author, publish etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This article talks about the specifics of how they are applied:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/configuring-osgi.html?cq_ck=1368002864971#ConfigurationDetails

> Resolution of multiple Run Modes
>
> For run mode specific configurations, multiple run modes can be
>   combined. For example, you can create configuration folders in the
>   following style:
>
> /apps/*/config../
>
> Configurations in such folders will be applied if all run modes match
>   a run mode defined at startup.
>
> For example, if an instance was started with the run modes
>   author,dev,emea, configuration nodes in /apps/*/config.emea,
>   /apps/*/config.author.dev/ and /apps/*/config.author.emea.dev/ will be
>   applied, while configuration nodes in /apps/*/config.author.asean/ and
>   /config/author.dev.emea.noldap/ will not be applied.
>
> If multiple configurations for the same PID are applicable, the
>   configuration with the highest number of matching run modes is
>   applied.
>
> For example, if an instance was started with the run modes
>   author,dev,emea, and both /apps/*/config.author/ and
>   /apps/*/config.emea.author/ define a configuration for
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl, the configuration
>   in/apps/*/config.emea.author/ will be applied.
>
> This rule's granularity is at a PID level. You cannot define some
>   properties for the same PID in/apps/*/config.author/ and more specific
>   ones in /apps/*/config.emea.author/ for the same PID. The
>   configuration with the highest number of matching run modes will be
>   effective for the entier PID.

Here are some best practices:

- https://aemmastery.com/runmodes-best-practices-8daa8a2c6582
- https://blog.kristianwright.com/2013/08/21/aem-best-practice-osgi-configurations/

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you create a aem instance using java -jar command, you can mention the run mode of aem instance prod, stage, author, publish etc.

This is what mapped to apps/myproject - config.* folder names.

Answer (score 0):

configurations are picked up top to low . i.e. .prod will get applied to all prod instances and superseded by one level prod.active. ... once configuration are created, instances running need to have run modes added to it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Configurations in such folders will be applied if all run modes match a run mode defined at startup.

As per your example, if an instance was started with the run modes author,nosamplecontent,prod,active

```
/apps
  /myproject
    - config   ---> will be applied
    - config.prod  ---> will be applied
    - config.author  ----> will be applied
    - config.active    ----> will be applied
    - config.prod.active ----> will be applied
    - config.prod.author.active ---> will be applied
```

Configurations that you provide in these folders generally are for specific PID. If multiple configurations for the same PID are applicable, the configuration with the highest number of matching run modes is applied.

So for e.g. if you had configuration for resourceresolver in config.prod as well as config.prod.active (but not in any other folder) then configuration for the resource resolver will be active from config.prod.active since that matches the higher number of runmodes applied.